# MongoDB aggregation on location data: Skip document/row if no movement

Tags: mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have data as sampled below.

I would like to query the location data from MongoDB and skip rows (or documents in my case) where no movement happens. I can't group by location (lon and lat) as a location can be used as a start/end point multiple times.

Basically: $skip if lat and lon is the same as in the document with the timestamp earlier to the current one.

In the sample I would want to skip the second and fourth document.

I figured that should be somehow possible with $skip in aggregation and and a $cond or $lookup operation.

Thanks in advance!

````
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "5ee4dbe8d30bb8f72598731a"},
    "vehicle": "CF729EE12AA98C3673266DF965FD89CB4C8D2E84",
    "lat": 52.51312,
    "lon": 13.317027,
    "timestamp": {"$date": "2020-06-10T11:10:48.040Z"}
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "5ee4dbe8d30bb8f725987c24"},
    "vehicle": "CF729EE12AA98C3673266DF965FD89CB4C8D2E84",
    "lat": 52.51312,
    "lon": 13.317027,
    "timestamp": {"$date": "2020-06-10T11:16:22.662Z"}
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "5ee4dc21d30bb8f725a33905"},
    "vehicle": "CF729EE12AA98C3673266DF965FD89CB4C8D2E84",
    "lat": 52.53564,
    "lon": 13.42169,
    "timestamp": {"$date": "2020-06-11T15:57:50.290Z"}
  },
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "5ee4dc21d30bb8f725a3421d"},
    "vehicle": "CF729EE12AA98C3673266DF965FD89CB4C8D2E84",
    "lat": 52.53564,
    "lon": 13.42169,
    "timestamp": {"$date": "2020-06-11T16:03:23.421Z"}
  }
]```
````

Comment: `$skip` only takes a positive integer as the number of documents to skip from the previous stage. You could use `$group` with `$first`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't be sure that the same location would not be present a second time in the data - it's actually unlikely that a location would only be present once - so I can't $group on lon and lat

Comment: So it's possible that there are documents without `lat` and `lon` ? can't you just filter them out before using `$group` ? I still don't get why you can't `$group` on `lat` and `lon` if you want to eliminate documents without movements, how else would you check if not `lat` and `lon`?

Comment: No, all the documents have lat and lon. What I mean by movement is that for the "vehicle" I see  a change of lat/lon for the next timestamp. But it's quite probable that a "vehicle" will have the same lat/lon later - so if I just group by lat/lon I will only get a single occurance of the "vehicle" having the lat/lon.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, I think the easiest way is to do it in your application layer. There is no direct way to do it in MongoDB. You could perhaps use `$reduce` to do it, but it would be compute and memory intensive on large dataset, so it's better to do a post processing if you can.